# How can i remove the Subscript range error from ReDim preserve

Tags: excel, vba

Getting subscript error on ReDim preserve

```
Function get_missing_refs(ref_range, sheet_range)

    Dim missing_refs() As String
    ReDim missing_refs(sheet_range.Count)
    Dim ret_cell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As Range

    i = 0

    For Each c In sheet_range
        'Set ret_cell = ref_range.Find(what:=c.Value, after:=ref_range.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt_:=xlWhole, Searchorder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        Set ret_cell = ref_range.Find(what:=c.Value, after:=ref_range.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
            :=xlWhole, Searchorder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
            False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If ret_cell Is Nothing Then
            missing_refs(i) = c.Value
            i = i + 1
        End If

    Next

   ReDim preserve missing_refs(i - 1)


    get_missing_refs = missing_refs



End Function
```

Comment: You'd get that if `i` equals 0 when it tries to redim.  You're increasing the value of `I` if the `Find` function doesn't find anything.  Should the line be `If Not ret_cell Is Nothing Then` so it increases `I` if a value is found?

Comment: It opposes what i want, but it removed the error but on the other hand it removes all the sheets data. i have to apply some check

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do as you haven't explained that part.  From the look of your code you're passing the function two ranges of cells.  You're then going through each cell in `sheet_range` and seeing if it also occurs in `ref_range`, if it's not you're adding the value to your array and returning an array of values that are missing from `ref_range`.  Is that correct?

Comment: Try using `ReDim Preserve missing_refs(UBound(missing_refs) - 1)` instead.  This will lower the upper limit by 1.  If `sheet_range` is 5 cells and nothing is found then it will return an array of 5 empty strings - `missing_refs(0)="", missing_refs(1)=""`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a check to see if value of i is less then 1

If it is; it means the array you have created is empty. You can just return null in this case

Your code will become:

```
Function get_missing_refs(ref_range, sheet_range)

Dim missing_refs() As String
ReDim missing_refs(sheet_range.Count)
Dim ret_cell As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim c As Range

i = 0

For Each c In sheet_range
    'Set ret_cell = ref_range.Find(what:=c.Value, after:=ref_range.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt_:=xlWhole, Searchorder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    Set ret_cell = ref_range.Find(what:=c.Value, after:=ref_range.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
        :=xlWhole, Searchorder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If ret_cell Is Nothing Then
        missing_refs(i) = c.Value
        i = i + 1
    End If

Next

if i = 0 then
    get_missing_refs = null
else
    ReDim preserve missing_refs(i - 1)
    get_missing_refs = missing_refs
end if


End Function
```

When calling this function you can check the array by using isnull function
for example you can write as below

```
ret_array = get_missing_refs(ref_range, sheet_range)
if IsNull(ret_array) then
    ' The return array is null
    ' code for case where the returned array is null
else
    ' The return array has value
    ' code for case where the returned array has value
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on guess work on what you're after, you could use a collection instead of an array.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim a As Collection
    Dim b As Variant
    Dim range_to_delete As Range
    Dim range_to_delete_from As Range

    Set range_to_delete_from = Sheet1.Range("B1:B5")

    Set a = get_missing_refs(Sheet1.Range("A1:A5"), range_to_delete_from)

    'Create a range from the missing value cells and then clear or delete.
    If a.Count > 0 Then
        For Each b In a
            If range_to_delete Is Nothing Then
                Set range_to_delete = range_to_delete_from.Parent.Range(b)
            Else
                Set range_to_delete = Union(range_to_delete, range_to_delete_from.Parent.Range(b))
            End If
        Next b
        'Delete the cells and move remaining cells up:
        'range_to_delete.Delete Shift:=xlUp

        'Or remove the value.
        range_to_delete.ClearContents

    Else
        Debug.Print "Nothing returned."
    End If

End Sub

Function get_missing_refs(ref_range As Range, sheet_range As Range) As Collection

    Dim missing_refs As Collection
    Dim c As Range
    Dim ret_cell As Range

    Set missing_refs = New Collection
    For Each c In sheet_range
        Set ret_cell = ref_range.Find(what:=c.Value, after:=ref_range.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
            :=xlWhole, Searchorder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
            False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If ret_cell Is Nothing Then
            missing_refs.Add c.Address
        End If
    Next c

    Set get_missing_refs = missing_refs

End Function
```

Have updated so that a range reference is returned for the missing values and the cells are either cleared or deleted.

Comment: I've updated the code.  Is this closer to what you're after?